# SQL query classic models database

Tags: mysql

Report the number of orders on Hold for each customer

```
SELECT customerName , count(*) As 'Orders on Hold'
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders
ON customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
WHERE orders.status = 'On Hold'
GROUP BY customerName;
```

this query currently just outputs the number of orders that have a status on hold but i need the total of orders on hold for each customers.
how would i achieve that.

Orders :
Customer Number 
status

Customers: 
CustomerNumber 
CustomerName

Comment: Could you please specify which RDBMS you are using, and the create scripts for the tables you are using in your example?

Comment: just did that..

Comment: What do you mean by "total of orders"? How is this different from the "number of orders"?

Comment: that was not wat I asked for. I asked for a create script for the relevant tables so we can easily reproduce your problem, and please leave out the tables irrelevant to this question.

Comment: same thing.  i need the number of orders on hold for each query and if the customer has no query on hold put a 0 in the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
create table customers
(
  customerNumber int,
  customerName varchar(50)
); 

create table orders
(
  orderNumber int,
  status varchar(10),
  customerNumber int
);

insert into customers values(1, 'A');
insert into customers values(2, 'B');

insert into orders values(101, 'Active', 1);
insert into orders values(102, 'On Hold', 1);
insert into orders values(103, 'On Hold', 1);

SELECT 
    customers.customerNumber, 
    count(orders.customerNumber) as 'Orders On Hold'
FROM
    customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON 
    customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber
    and orders.status = 'On Hold'
GROUP BY customers.customerNumber
```

Returns:

```
customerNumber     Orders On Hold
==============     ==============
1                  2
2                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on the new request

```
SELECT C.customerName , sum(CASE WHEN O.status = 'On Hold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As 'Orders on Hold', COUNT(O.orderNumber) as 'Total Orders'
FROM customers AS C
INNER JOIN orders AS O ON C.customerNumber = O.customerNumber
GROUP BY C.customerName;
```

Comment: i dont need anything to do with amount. just need the total number of orders on hold for each customer

Comment: Update the answer. hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: doesnt do what is expected